# How to correctly do a double SHA256 hashing?

Tags: python, hash, cryptography, sha256

This might be basic stuff, but am pretty new to coding in general.

How do you properly do a double sha256 code?

For example, for the string "abc" the correct output of the double hash should be: 4f8b42c22dd3729b519ba6f68d2da7cc5b2d606d05daed5ad5128cc03e6c6358

However, in the script I provide below, I get another output, altough I do not know where I went wrong. What am I missing in the code?

```
abc = 'abc'.encode("utf-8")

hashed_abc = hashlib.sha256(abc)

hashed_abc = hashlib.sha256(hashed_abc.hexdigest().encode('utf-8'))
print((hashed_abc.hexdigest()))
```

Thank you.

Comment: All of the search results I see for "double hashing" involve buckets and hash tables. Are you sure that's the correct term -- could you clarify what double hashing is, in the context of your own question?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark I believe they mean hashing a sha256 hash again.

Answer (score 2):

```py
import hashlib
import binascii
 
def doubleSha256(hex): 
   bin = binascii.unhexlify(hex)
   hash = hashlib.sha256(bin).digest()
   hash2 = hashlib.sha256(hash).digest()
   print("Input Hex: "+str(hex,"ascii"))
   print("SHA256:\n   "+str(binascii.hexlify(hash),"ascii"))
   print("Double-SHA256:\n   "+str(binascii.hexlify(hash2),"ascii"))
```

You could use something like this and it works for me.

To add:

If you are having trouble passing in “abc” use this.

```
ascii = "abc"
hex = binascii.hexlify(bytes(ascii,"ascii"))
doubleSha256(hex)
```

Comment: The above is, in fact, the meaning of double sha256.  The results of sha256 are a binary string that is then directly fed into a second sha256.

Comment: Well, to be honest, the conversion from hex to binary should not be part of the double hashing.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Believe thats the only way to do it, but do provide another answer if you find another way.

Comment: The function is called `sha256d` in most code, and I would just perform the double hashing and leave the hex encoding / decoding and print statements out of it.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes is right. Hash functions are operating on binary data. `doubleSha256` must accept binary data. And, [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) already accepts binary data. Your code changes direction on the style of the coding and standards.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes because it is taken from a [web page](https://www.herongyang.com/Bitcoin/Block-Data-Calculate-Double-SHA256-with-Python.html) that does not testest against at least the hello test of the bitcoin.

Answer (score 0):

Cryptographic hash functions are working on bytes and output bytes, too. The double SHA256 or written as SHA256D should work in this way, too.

```py
import hashlib
import binascii
 
   
def SHA256D(data): 

   hash = hashlib.sha256(data).digest()

   #Uncomment me for testing
   #print(hashlib.sha256(data.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() )
      
   return hashlib.sha256(hash).digest()
   
   
toHashB = "hello".encode('utf-8')

print(SHA256D(toHashB))

doublehashed = SHA256D(toHashB)

print( binascii.hexlify(doublehashed).decode('utf8'))
```

The double SHA256 hash of the string "hello" is given as an example on [Bitcoin pages](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#Hashes).
This outputs

`9595c9df90075148eb06860365df33584b75bff782a510c6cd4883a419833d50`

---

Note that the other answer had two problems;

1. There is an error on the string "hello" `binascii.Error: Odd-length string`
2. The SHA256D executes the hex decoding and encoding. This should be outside of the SHA256D